# How can I make QtCreator compile multiple cpp and header files?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I have a function implemented in a cpp file and declared in header file. In the main program cpp file I include the header file and use the function. However this fails to link (undefined reference to myFunc). What do I have to change to get it working?

EDIT: pro file:

```
SOURCES += as241.c \
    main.cpp \
    normalvar.cpp \
    normaldistribution.cpp \
    studenttdistribution.cpp
LIBS += -lgsl \
    -lgslcblas \
    -lm
HEADERS += as241.h \
    var.h \
    distribution.h \
    normalvar.h \
    normaldistribution.h \
    studenttdistribution.h
```

In main.cpp I use a function from as241

as241.h:

```
#ifndef AS241_H
#define AS241_H

double ppnd16(double p);

#endif // AS241_H
```

as241.cpp:

```
#include "as241.h"
#include <math.h>

double ppnd16(double p)
{
  //code
}
```

Comment: what is the content of your *.pro file?

Comment: 5K rep, and you don't know how to ask a question - a bit sad, I would say.

Comment: can you post the output of make on the shell? BTW, IMHO this is no longer a stackoverflow question. How about re-asking in http://qtcentre.org?

Comment: You say `as241.c` in your .pro, but `as241.cpp` before the code excerpt - accident or the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure without seeing the code, but in yout *.h file (the one that matches the *.c file) you should do:

```
extern c{
// old c code
}
```

Comment: All the files I mentioned are added to the project.